# Getting Started with Compass and Sass

Tags: rubygems, sass, compass-sass

I am setting up my MBP to start diving into Compass and Sass development but I am having some slight issues. One of the issues I am having is certain gems will not install properly. I've installed susy, sass and compass and then I went to install oily_gem and get the following error:

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>   ERROR:  Error installing oily_png:
>     ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
>    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
> ```
>
> mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h
>
> Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/oily_png-1.0.2 for inspection.
>   Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/oily_png-1.0.2/ext/oily_png/gem_make.out

Compass and Sass are working just fine but there are a few gems that I get this same error on. Any ideas as to why this would happen? Have I missed a step somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
sudo gem install oily_png
```

in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the header package(s) for ruby. I don't know the name of the packages in your system, but in mine, for example, I need to have `ruby1.8-dev` or `ruby-dev` installed in order to install some gems (note the *-dev* suffix.)